# How can I destruct the text which I copied by Ctrl+C?

Tags: command-line, clipboard

Is it possible to destruct the text which I copied with a Terminal command without using any program like clipboard managers? The text I copy gets destructed if I restart my computer. However, I need to destruct my copied text without restarting my computer.

Comment: Copy something else.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60937438/how-to-clear-the-clipboard-in-debian-buster-via-terminal#:~:text=You%20can%20clear%20the%20X,with%20sudo%20apt%20install%20xclip%20).&text=You%20may%20need%20to%20first,running%20X11%20on%20display%20zero.

Comment: ... or `xclip -sel c -i < /dev/null`